# No valid versions available for pinkie-promise

Tags: npm

It appears the npm module pinkie-promise, which is a dependency of some module in my project, is not longer available.

Does anyone know how to identify which module requires this module as a dependency so that I can try and replace it with an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting around on npm, install pinkie-promise by pointing to their github repo.

`npm install https://github.com/floatdrop/pinkie-promise.git`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an NPM failure. It makes sense to wait and retry later.